# Test cases using Chai and mocha

Tags: javascript, chai, testcase

I have following function:

```
function showAllUrlsData(inputUrl, inputUrlPromise) {
      fetch(inputUrl)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.text()
        })
        .then(function(result) {
          var inputObjectData =  htmlResult(result);
          inputObjData(inputObjectData, inputUrl ,inputUrlPromise);
      });
    }
```

how to write the test cases using fetch? I'm very new to this test case framework,any inputs will be really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting code it is helpful to readers to post code using styles outlined in the https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help guide. This makes the code readable and your question more likely to get answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fetch-mock](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock). Install with

```
npm i -D fetch-mock
```

Then use it like this to mock a fetch:

```
var fetchMock = require('fetch-mock');
var makeRequest = require('./make-request');

// Mock the fetch() global to always return the same value for GET
// requests to all URLs.
fetchMock.get('*', { hello: 'world' });

makeRequest().then(function(data) {
  console.log('got data', data);
});

// Unmock.
fetchMock.reset();
```

For more information here's the [documentation](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/)